# ESTA US Application

Tags: esta, application-status, irish-citizens

I am an Irish citizen and was planning a holiday with friends to New York next year. I am a full time mother and I am currently unemployed. Would I be refused entry to the US on an ESTA Application due to this because I can't provide details of work? I can't find any information on this anywhere.

Comment: The ESTA form asks whether 'you have a current or former employer', to which you can honestly answer 'yes' if you ever had an employer.

Comment: I just had a look at it and as you said it does say 'a current or previous employer'. So hopefully I can just put in a previous and employer and see how it goes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This question has two parts: the ESTA itself requires no proof of funds. It'd be hard for it to require one since it's valid for two years for multiple entry.

At the border you *might* be required to provide a proof of funds but I've been crossing the border for eight years now, in total close to a hundred times now and this never happened.

This is very different to a B1/B2 visa process where you most definitely will be asked a proof of funds.